# how to enable asp.net checkboxlist from javascript?

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I am trying to enable my checkboxlist from js? this is my code sofar:

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script>
        function enabledCBL() {
            document.getelementbyid('CheckBoxList1').disabled = false;
        }

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <button onclick="enabledCBL()">enable</button>
        <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server" TextAlign="Right">
            <asp:ListItem Text="een">

            </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="twee">

            </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="drie">

            </asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Text="vier">

            </asp:ListItem>
        </asp:CheckBoxList>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: check your html output for CheckBoxList real id

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case-sensitive. Your statement must be:

```
document.getElementById('CheckBoxList1').disabled = false;
```

Try,

```
function enabledCBL() {
        var tab = document.getElementById('CheckBoxList1');

        var checkboxes = tab.getElementsByTagName("input");
        for (i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++)
            checkboxes[i].disabled = false;
    }
```

The `<button>` tag does postback you need to add type attribute to the button.

```
<button type="button"  onclick="enabledCBL()">
            enable</button>
```

Comment: @user603007 - I've post correct syntax. CheckboxList render HTML table so you have to enable each element in it.

Comment: @user603007 - You have to try jQuery for better compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Please set your `CheckBoxList` with `ClientIDMode="Static"` then try again. If not specify ClientIDMode it will generate some id like `ct001_CheckBoxList`

Read more:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck the items in checkboxlist But i have tired the enable checklist in javascript..But its not working for me..Hope this code will help you . So for I posted here.

```
function Validate()
{
var tableBody = document.getElementById('CheckBoxList1').childNodes[0];
for (var i=0;i<tableBody.childNodes.length; i++)
{
var currentTd = tableBody.childNodes[i].childNodes[0];
var listControl = currentTd.childNodes[0];
if (listControl.checked==true)
{
listControl.checked = false;
}
}
}


<asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxList1" runat="server"  TextAlign="Right">
        <asp:ListItem Text="aa">
        </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="twee">
        </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="drie">
        </asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Text="vier">
        </asp:ListItem>
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

I have seen an Example based on your needs in Jquery Refer this link [Jquery](http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/QpAz6/)